# What are these computational statistics concerning French words?

Tags: linguistique, lexique, dictionnaires

Or where can I find them ? It requires computational language, I hope these calculations have been done before.

I'm seeking the minimum, median (not average) and maximum of the aspects below, for the French words contained in a small dictionary (e.g. Petit Larousse, not in a corpus) :

- n° of syllables
- n° of letters
- n° of synonyms
- n° of words in proxemy (lexical field)
- n° of paronyms
- n° of explosive consonants
- n° of alliterations
- n° of assonances
- rapport n° of vowels / n° of consonants
- % of words starting with a consonant

So for example for the n° of letters I would like to know how many letters the smallest word has, how many letters the longest word has and how many letters most words have.

Answer (score 4):

<sub><sub>Je réponds en français vu que tu es manifestement francophone</sub></sub>

Le Petit Larousse ne fournit pas ses données librement.

Voici quelques-unes des valeurs recherchées calculées à partir de la base [Lexique](http://www.lexique.org/):

Nombre de syllabes : min 1, max 9, median 3
Nombre de lettres :  min 1, max 25, median 9
Nombre de voyelles sur nombre de lettres: min 0, max 100, median 42.86%
Pourcentage de mots commençant par une consonne : 78%

Comment: Merci lexique.org est une précieuse ressource.